# How to handle square brackets in XPath

Tags: java, xpath

My Application has to calculate the XPath of the HTML-Element that the user clicks on. In this case I tried to click on the "Sign Up" button from Stackoverflow.com

Here is the DOM of the clicked HTML-Element:

```
<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">
    <body class="question-page new-topbar no-grid-comments no-grid-post-layout">
        <header class="top-bar js-top-bar _fixed">
            <div class="-container">
                <div class="-actions">
                    <div class="-ctas">
                        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=head&amp;returnurl=%2fusers%2fstory%2fcurrent" class="login-link btn-topbar-primary" rel="nofollow" data-ga="["Sign Up","Sign Up Navigation","Header",null,null]">Sign Up</a>
```

As you can see, the last Element in this dom is a `<a>` tag, that contains the attribute:

`data-ga="["Sign Up","Sign Up Navigation","Header",null,null]`

My application calculated this XPath for the HTML-Element:

`/HTML/BODY[@class='questions-page new-topbar']/HEADER[@class='top-bar js-top-bar _fixed']/DIV[@class='-container']/DIV[@class='-actions']/DIV[@class='-ctas']/A[@href='https://stackoverflow.com/users/signup?ssrc=head&returnurl=%2fusers%2fstory%2fcurrent' and @class='login-link btn-topbar-primary' and @rel='nofollow' and @data-ga='['Sign Up','Sign Up Navigation','Header',null,null]']`

When I tested the XPath I got an error, that no element could be found. I traced the error down and found out that, if I remove `and @data-ga='['Sign Up','Sign Up Navigation','Header',null,null]'` from my XPath, everything is working, but I cant simply remove attributes, so my question is: **How do I properly escape the nested square brackets in my XPath?**

Comment: Your HTML is not valid. You need to set single quote marks within the data-ga attribute: `data-ga="['Sign Up','Sign Up Navigation','Header',null,null]"`

Comment: @mailivres thanks for pointing that out, maybe file a bug report and let stackoverflow know?

Comment: I guess it's a minor issue, which is handled by all browsers. But don't let me keep you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's not the square brackets that cause the trouble, its the quotes.

You've tagged the question Java, which means you should be able to use XPath 2.0 (e.g. via Saxon or Jaxen), which means you can escape quotes in a string literal by doubling them:

```
@data-ga='[''Sign Up'',''Sign Up Navigation'',''Header'',null,null]'
```

Unfortunately this is quite hard to achieve in the general case with XPath 1.0.

Comment: You seem to be right, its the quotes that are causing me trouble. I will take a look into the libraries you mentioned, thanks.